# kernel appears to have died

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

i am a newbie, please reply either it is right or wrong

i am running a transfer learning model on azure note books

while executing the epochs cell i got the error kernel apperas to have died it will restart automatically

but it stuck there

```
          keras import applications
          #Load the base model, not including its final connected layer, and set the input shape to 
          match our images
          base_model = keras.applications.vgg16.VGG16(weights='imagenet', include_top=False, 
          input_shape=train_generator.image_shape)



          from keras import Model
          from keras.layers import Flatten, Dense
          from keras import optimizers

          # Freeze the already-trained layers in the base model
          for layer in base_model.layers:
          layer.trainable = False

          # Create layers for classification of our images
          x = base_model.output
          x = Flatten()(x)
          prediction_layer = Dense(len(classes), activation='sigmoid')(x) 
          model = Model(inputs=base_model.input, outputs=prediction_layer)

          # Compile the model
          opt = optimizers.Adam(lr=0.001)
          model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',optimizer=opt,metrics=['accuracy'])

          # Now print the full model, which will include the layers of the base model plus the dense 
          layer we added
          print(model.summary())
```

After this i got layers, outputshape and parameters in layers

```
          num_epochs = 1
          history = model.fit_generator(  train_generator,
                                           steps_per_epoch = train_generator.samples // batch_size,
                                           validation_data = validation_generator, 
                                           validation_steps = validation_generator.samples // 
                                           batch_size,
                                           epochs = num_epochs)
```

after this cell i am getting error kernel appears to have died

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Just restart the kernel and try again.

2.There can be many reason for a kernel to die:

Out of storage

Inactivity

Ran out of GPU etc.